# Есть 2 функции с одинаковой структурой, но разными деталями. Как избавиться от дублирования?

Tags: java, рефакторинг

Есть две функции:

```
private void sendLeft() {
    leftSendersIndexes = newLeftSendersIndexes;
    Agent rightRecepient;
    int rightRecepientIdx = 0;
    Agent leftSender;
    for (int i = 0; i < leftSendersIndexes.size(); i++) {
        rightRecepientIdx = leftSendersIndexes.get(i) + 1;
        rightRecepient = list.get(rightRecepientIdx);
        leftSender = list.get(rightRecepientIdx - 1);
        rightRecepient.setNewLeftMsg(leftSender.getLeftMsg());
        rightRecepient.setLeftMsg(0); // reset left messages
    }
}

private void sendRight() {
    rightSendersIndexes = newRightSendersIndexes;
    Agent leftRecepient;
    int leftRecepientIdx = 0;
    Agent rightSender;
    for (int i = 0; i < rightSendersIndexes.size(); i++) {
        leftRecepientIdx = rightSendersIndexes.get(i) - 1;
        leftRecepient = list.get(leftRecepientIdx);
        rightSender = list.get(leftRecepientIdx + 1);
        leftRecepient.setNewRightMsg(rightSender.getRightMsg());
    }
}
```

Они очень похожи. Но все портит что в первой функции сначала + 1, а потом минус 1, а во второй функции наоборот. К тому же в конце вызывается `setNewLeftMsg()` в первом случае и `setNewRightMsg()` во втором. Мне приходит на ум только один вариант: ввести булевский параметр. А нет лучше способа?

Comment: У вас 2 достаточно простых и последовательных функции. Сделав из них одну более сложную и запутанную - упростите ли вы себе жизнь?

Comment: @KromStern, пожалуй что нет) Просто слышал что дублирования под страхом смертной казни нельзя допускать). А тут же получается дублирование.

Comment: Если бы дело было только в +|- 1. Не известно что у вас за agent-ы. Да ещё и внешние. И функции у них вызываются разные. Замучаетесь условия втыкать.

Comment: Последние строки в обеих функциях намекают, что архитектурные проблемы есть повыше того, что приведено.